# How to Use NPM Install With Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, npm-install

I'm seeing a lot of sites offering the ability to install their library using "npm install", but I have no clue how to use it. Tried reading up on it, but no one gives a real... first things first... type answer. Are you supposed to install something first in your Windows operating system? Or is their a plug-in/add-in that needs to be installed in Visual Studio? Then, how do you actually run the "npm install blah" line that these sites instruct?

Comment: I assume you want to create a single Visual Studio Solution which contains two Projects:   (1) a web client (website) Project and (2) an MVC server Project.  If that is correct, look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70025016/how-can-i-combine-an-angular-9-spa-project-and-an-asp-net-core-2-2-mvc-project-i

Comment: To use "npm" commands you must have installed Node.js into the "client folder" of your website project.  If you want to create Angular client projects, install Angular/CLI, TypeScript, etc in the same client folder.  I use Cmd.exe shell to install these in my client project folder.